Why pyautogui has a 2 seconds lag in locateOnScreen?
I'm trying to create a bot that will do the fishing for me in a game.
In some place on the screen after a couple of time, they will appear from 1 to 5, for now I'm testing this code only with number 1. After this, the number will appear. I need to press "2" button once to catch the fish ( when number 5 appears I need to press 5 times this button), but I need to be quick and that's the problem, because pyautogui waits like 2 seconds to check this image, and after that my fish is gone. How can I remove these 2 second lag in this script? I tried to run this script on my old PC and on super new, but the lag always was 2 seconds.
Here is my code:
import pyautogui
pyautogui.PAUSE = 0.01
pyautogui.FAILSAFE = True
import time
import pydirectinput      # I used this to force pyautogui to use keyboard on game



while True:
    try:
        if pyautogui.locateOnScreen("1.jpg", confidence=0.8, grayscale=True, region=(200,255,340,340)):
            print("I see you")
            pydirectinput.press('2', presses=1) # I used this to force use keyboard on game
            time.sleep(3)

            continue
    except pyautogui.ImageNotFoundException:
         # Not found I guess
        pass
    print("I can't see you")
    time.sleep(0.1)

I want to remove these 2 second lag at the beginning of pyautogui.

What is your hardware here?  CPU and graphics?  Reading from the screen is never optimized, because that's not the important direction for graphics performance.  You might try replacing the locateOnScreen with a screenshot of the same region to see how long it takes.  And remember you intentionally have a 3 second delay after every key press.
